# my metamask account on rinkeby freeze forever

Tags: metamask, etherscan, rinkeby

[image]

I got this problem since yesterday and it never succeeded.
I tried to investigate the transaction on etherscan and it said "Sorry, We are unable to locate this TxnHash"
URL => https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x383b3220d647c2633c5b667e8093e2fe66bb605b2b462120eabbf38a9175dd40

I cannot cancel the transaction also.
I can no longer use this account anymore.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Send some TestNet Eth to yourself but change the nonce of the transaction to the nonce of this pending transaction.

For more detail, check this:https://help.tokensets.com/en/articles/4089766-how-to-push-through-a-stuck-transaction